# Safari 12 - Favicon in Gmail tab shows incorrect e-mail count

Tags: safari, high-sierra, gmail

I have enabled the **Show website icons in tabs** feature made available in Safari 12.

Gmail has a feature to show count of unread emails in the browser tab favicon. The count shown in the Gmail tab in Safari 12 is incorrect.

[image]

For these tabs, on the first I have a total of 4 e-mails in the inbox, while in the second I have 7. None of them are unread. These counts never change. Does anyone have a fix for this?

I'm running Safari 12.0 under macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no solution for this at the moment.

This is a known bug in Safari 12, and has to do with the way website favicons shown in Safari tabs are cached. My experience so far with Safari 12 in macOS High Sierra and macOS Mojave has been that favicon once cached for a website is not refreshed automatically.

- [Safari favicons don't support updating](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103767)

An advisable approach here would be to file a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/) with Apple. I have already done the same. Having more reports for same issue increases the likelihood of an issue getting resolved.